# How do I grep for special character(control characters) using hex representation

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

So while helping someone debug some code I realized that there were some weird characters in their output, namely � and �(\xc0 and \xd0 in hex).

I wanted to find these characters in a large text output file.

I've managed to locate these characters using sublime by enabling the regex option in find with `\xc0` or `\xd0` being the query. I have also managed to `grep` them by doing `grep $'\xc0' filename` in bash.

The thing that is bothering me right now is that, if I use the `-P` option for `grep`, it refuses to find these characters.

`grep -P "\xc0" filename` would print out nothing for a file that has that character in it(and the other two methods above would successfully find it), and this is bugging me so badly I want to know why this wouldn't work.

I have read a couple of other posts in which the `-P` option along with `"[\x80-\xff]"` are suggested but for some reason I just couldn't get them to work :\

`grep -P` has been a good friend for a long time until now :( Any help and tips are appreciated!

I'm using GNU grep.

**EDIT:**

I have actually tried on 2 linux distributions.

- On Ubuntu 14.04 with bash: My terminal doesn't seem to like the character :\

`printf "\xc0"` prints out nothing in the terminal, however printing it to a file with `>` and then opening in sublime would show the character.

```
printf "\xc0" > foo
grep $'\xc0' foo > out1
grep -P '\xc0' foo > out2
grep -P '\x{c0}' foo > out3
```

`out{1,2,3}` are all empty.

- On CentOS 7.2 with bash: `printf` prints something - the question mark dark thingy

`printf "\xc0"` prints out �(actually looks like this)

```
printf "\xc0" > foo
grep $'\xc0' foo > out1
grep -P '\xc0' foo > out2
grep -P '\x{c0}' foo > out3
```

Only `out1` contains the character.

Comment: I might have sounded angry and unwilling to learn in the original post but I do want to learn :) There's probably some caveat with `grep -P` I didn't know, and I'd be more than happy to find out about it :)

Comment: `I just couldn't get them to work` ? What errors did you see?

Comment: And did you try `grep -P "\x{c0}" filename`? Or even `"\x{00c0}"`?

Comment: What you pasted here are `\uFFFD` characters, you need `grep -P "\x{fffd}"` to match them.

Comment: Actually, the two characters I pasted above are probably wrong and lost in the copy-paste process.

Comment: @Inian: I don't see any errors, `grep` just outputs nothing as opposed to outputting the line containing the character.

Comment: Thanks guys! I have edited the original post to include some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## byte

What you need to do first is to create inside a variable the exact **byte** that you want to search.

Something like any of this:

```
a=$(echo -e '\xc0)
a=$'\xc0'
a=$(printf '\xc0')
a=$(echo -e '\300')     # 300 is 0xC0 in octal
a=$'\300'
a=$(printf '\300')
a=$(echo "c0" | xxd -r -p)
```

I could try to come up with some other ways, but I hope you get the idea.

Then, you could try to search for the `byte` with grep:

```
echo $'Testing this: \xC0 byte' |  grep "$a"
```

And, if you use a locale with utf-8 (as is the most common) that will fail.
If you change to a ISO-8859-1 locale, that will work:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.iso88591 echo $'Testing this: \xC0 byte' |
LC_ALL=en_US.iso88591  grep -P "$a"
```

Or, if you don't mind starting a new bash instance:

```
$ bash
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.iso88591
$ echo $'Testing this: \xC0 byte' |  grep -P "$a"
```

And just return to the old bash environment by executing `exit`.
This might work or not depending on your system.

Let's explore the other side: characters.

## character

There is a very very important twist that you should understand.
A byte is not a character. Well, sometimes, by sheer luck, it is.

But beside those 128 ASCII characters in which a byte is a character (not in UTF-16 or UTF-32. And let's also forget about [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)), all 1,114,112 (17 × 65,536) UNICODE code points have more than one byte <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)</sup>.

In that case, you should ask for the UNICODE code point of hex `0xC0`.
In modern bash, like this:

```
$ printf '\U00C0`
À
```

Which is [this character: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c0/index.htm)

That will be encoded as one byte if the locale is ISO-8859-1 (and ISO-8859-15, at least) and as two bytes if the locale is utf-8.

```
$ a=$(printf '\UC0')
$ printf 'Testing \U00C0 character' | grep -P "$a"
Testing À character
```

It also will work if you change the LC_ALL variable. Well, I mean that grep will detect the character, but the printed line may fail to render correctly the character due to the changed locale.

If the file has this *character* and the encoding of the file is correct.   Grep will work with the value of the character in a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I always got confused with character encodings and all this. On my Ubuntu machine `printf '\U00c0'` indeed prints that character to my terminal now. So `printf '\xc0'` not displaying was because of the locale of the shell(I was able to see it in sublime if I printed to file)?

Comment: One of the main reasons I was confused was that I could use the `\xc0` regex expression to search for the character in sublime, while I can't seem to do it with `grep`'s `-P` option, as seen in many other posts I have seen, for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695609/how-to-grep-for-presence-of-specific-hex-bytes-in-files) and [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19491/how-to-specify-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes-in-grep).

Comment: @a283626086 You can use `\xc0` in sublime because it is **assuming** a specific code page (only 256 characters), probably ISO-8859-1 (in USA) or ISO-8859-5 (in Russia) or ISO-8859-7 (Greece). In that limited charset, the byte C0 means a specific character À, Р or ΐ (respectively for the code pages above). But that also means that the character used could change when a code page is changed. That sublime choose one character set is just a limitation it has.  UTF-8 breaks that limit. Embrace UTF-8 and be free to write any character.