# Bytewise grep fails for some byte values

Tags: bash, grep, hex

I am studying the [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) format, and I tried to [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) its magic bytes, 1F 8B, in a sample archive. I used the manual from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17168847/2159939).

```
xxd a.gz
```

Output:

```
00000000: 1f8b 0800 43dc 605b 0003 4bcb cf4f 4a2c  ....C.`[..K..OJ,
00000010: e202 0047 972c b207 0000 00              ...G.,.....
```

---

```
grep -obUaP "\x1f" a.gz
```

Output:

```
0:
```

---

```
grep -obUaP "\x8b" a.gz
```

Output:

```
# Nothing is printed
```

For some reason, grep finds one byte and does not find another. After some investigation, we had a blind guess that it fails on bytes with the [most significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Bit_significance_and_indexing) set. However, we couldn't find any reasonable explanation.

Why does it happen and is there a workaround?

Comment: Probably because your `grep` works with UTF-8.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Brilliant. Adding LC_ALL=C helped. Please make it an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because `grep` is working with UTF-8; when you search for "\x8b" it's looking for 0xc2 0x8b. You will need to either find some way to disable grep's UTF-8 support, or switch to a tool that strictly interprets the search criteria as binary values.