# Grep hex characters in a file

Tags: unix, grep

I am having some difficulty finding the number of hex characters in a file. For example:

```
grep -o \x02 file | wc -l
0
```

There should be about 3M matches here, but it doesn't seem like the `\x02` character is being recognized here. For example (in python):

```
>>> s=open('file').read()
>>> s.count('\x02')
2932267
```

Comment: Try `grep -c ...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell -- still get the same result (on Mac btw).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17168847/10622916 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/23757973/10622916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) may be OK for MacOS but doesn't seem to work on debian using bash (tested with bash 4.4, grep 2.27).

I could get a match using the `-P` directive (for Perl regex)

```
user@host:~ $ printf '\x02\n3\n\x02' | grep -c -P '\x02'
2
user@host:~ $ printf '\x02\n3\n\x02' | grep -c -P '\xFF' #same input, different pattern
0
user@host:~ $ printf '\x02\n3\n\xff' | grep -c -P '\xFF' #match with unmatching case
2
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want on macOS:

```
printf "\x02\n3\n\x02" | grep -c "\x02"
2
```